# implement Voice recognition for number detection in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, shared-libraries, voice-recognition

I want to use a model in my app to recognize the voice , it's better be a offline model.
and a important one is i want to recognize numbers.is there any trained model to just recognize numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few examples here on SO for offline speach recongnition. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652373/offline-google-voice-recognition-on-android) und [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean). In the second one they are also talking about the google speech api which works since api level 23 offline. This are generell voice recongnition and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465285/get-numbers-from-android-voice-regnition) are someone that cuts out only the numbers of it.